# AES encryption for storing data on cookie

Tags: php, cookies, encryption, aes, formula

I need to store the maximum chars as possible on a cookie having char string to store encrypted in AES.

cookie has about 4kb  memory.

So i need to count how much chars i can store in a cookie encrypting in AES all these chars.

chars to store is an alphanumerical string.

EDIT: i can allow all the UTF-8 alphanumeric chars both in plaintext and in chipertext

THIS IS MY PIECE OF CODE

```
 <?php


$Pass = "132ksjcngpt04938idjsk39urtokg";
$Clear = "123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123456789012345678901234567890123456789o";


$crypted = fnEncrypt($Clear, $Pass);
echo "Encrypred: ".$crypted."<br></br>";

$newClear = fnDecrypt($crypted, $Pass);
echo "Decrypred: ".$newClear."<br></br>";



function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
    return trim(
        base64_encode(
            mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                $sSecretKey, $sValue, 
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
                mcrypt_create_iv(
                    mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
                        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                    ), 
                    MCRYPT_RAND)
                )
            )
        );
}

function fnDecrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
    return trim(
        mcrypt_decrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
            $sSecretKey, 
            base64_decode($sValue), 
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
            mcrypt_create_iv(
                mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                    MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                ), 
                MCRYPT_RAND
            )
        )
    );
}
?>
```

I TESTED AND THIS IS THE RESULT:

```
Encrypred: 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

Decrypred: 123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123hryd{}ls.-''ksllasllallallallallal:{}::{}jdhhfn123456789012345678901234567890123456789o
```

chiperText  is compoused of 3040 utf-8 chars

encrypted is up to 4056 utf-8 chars

Comment: 1) AES is no hash. 2) The output size depends on the chaining mode. Which one are you using? CBC? 3) You probably need to add an IV and a MAC, else it's probably not secure. 4) Chars and bytes are not the same thing (assuming a sane type system).

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks for infos i'm newbie on this argument i would like to learn about it, i edited my answer to show you better (hope my english is good) what i need to do ;)

Comment: You're definition of characters is still unclear. Which characters are allowed in the plaintext, and which in ciphertext?

Comment: @CodesInChaos all utf-8 alphanumerical chars are allowed in plain text

Comment: ciphertext is the encrypted data

Comment: ok thx, in chiperText i can allow the same chars as for the plaintext, the important thing is that i need to not overflow the 4kb when encrypted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an authenticated streaming mode, such as AES-GCM, the *raw* ciphertext size in *bytes* will be 32 bytes larger than the plaintext size. 16 of those are for a random IV, and 16 for the MAC.

Now you have the problem that arbitrary bytes aren't valid UTF-8, so you need some encoding to take care of that. Base64 is a popular variant, but it increases the size to 4/3 of the original size.
This means if your size limit is 4KiB, you'll be able to support plaintexts of up to 3040 bytes.

There are other more efficient encodings, but that gets more complicated, and you'll need to figure out which characters are valid (such as `\0`). I don't recommend that unless absolutely necessary.

---

Your code has plenty of mistakes:

1. You're using ECB, pretty much the worst of all modes
2. You need the same IV for encryption and decryption. So store it alongside the ciphertext. You don't notice it, since ECB doesn't use an IV.
3. You don't have authentication.
4. Your IV generation isn't good. Use `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` instead of `MCRYPT_RAND`.

Comment: i'm going to use CBC mode it's ok?

Comment: CBC adds additional overhead (1-16 bytes), and you still need IV+MAC. CBC is a bit annoying, since you'll need to add a MAC yourself, which is easy to get wrong. AES-GCM with random IV (use a crypto PRNG) is what I recommend. It includes both authentication and encryption.

Comment: i updated question, can you check my code and edit if you want?

Comment: i tested my code, seems using 3040 chars i retrieve 4056 chars encrypted string, what about? i'm in 4kb? :)

Comment: @Ispuk That's pretty much what I predicted. One you add the IV and MAC you'll end up at 4096 characters, which is the 4KiB maximum you wanted. You'll still need to fix the flaws I pointed out, or your encryption isn't secure.

Comment: WOWOWOWOWOWOW , so man we are? i have 3040 utf-8 chars free right? :)

Comment: can you show me the right code to use? pleaseee :) than i will flag your answer you helped me a lot man!!

Comment: No, you'll need somebody who knows php better than I do for that.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I wrong but supposing you're using UTF-8 as alphanumerical character for your plain text, since AES works with 16 byte length blocks (that can be viewed as 16 alphanumerical character in this context), your plain text is at least padded with 15 byte (the worst scenario).

So, given `n` the length of your plain text, the resulting cipher text length can be inferred with:

```
(n + 16) - (n % 16)
```

Just my 2 cents.
Dario.

Comment: 1) You're assuming a mode like CBC 2) The output of AES isn't valid UTF-8, so you need to use an encoding like Base64 which increases the size. 3) Your formula misses IV and MAC

Comment: i will become crazy guys, please if someone can make some order in my head

Comment: @CodesInChaos i know you have the answer please give ti to me :)))